# Forgot the password on my older (encrypted) MacBookPro, looking for advanced/creative solution

Tags: hard-drive, encryption, passwords, macbook-pro

My old MBP laptop (retina, early/late 2014) ended up with some damage to the screen and wouldn't turn on anymore. I replaced it with another one, figuring everything I had on it was a loss. Fast forward to 1 year ago, I took out the hard drive and put it into an enclosure so I could hook it up via USB to another system to get my files off of it. Once I plugged it in to my laptop, the prompt came up for my password, which of course I hadn't even thought about in years. To make matters worse, I encrypted the drive as well. I've got a list of passwords I've attempted to no avail. I'd really like to be able to at least see what is on my drive, and here's what I've tried:

One thing I didn't try was trying to reset my password through Apple, bc I wasn't using the cloud at the time and had no online (or offline) backups.

So the thing I attempted last night was hooking up the drive to a Windows 10 Dell laptop, and tried viewing the files using HFSExplorer from catacombae.org.
This almost worked. But not quite, and I'm figuring it's because of the encryption because I was able to load part of the drive that apparently is not encrypted.

That's really as far as I've been able to get. Hopefully somebody out there has found a way around this! Thank you=)

Answer (score 1):

If the drive is encrypted, you're out of luck, sadly.

I do not know the specifics of the filesystem on the drive or how encryption works on it, but if it works anything like any other encryption you MUST have the authentication information in order to decrypt and access the files.

While it is theoretically possible to run a super computer against the password or against the data to determine the encryption key, any reasonable encryption system would require years of time from an exceptionally powerful supercomputer to do this, and so it is not practically possible.